# How to fix 403 Forbidden when accessing IIS site in Virtual Box from MacOS

Tags: macos, iis, virtualbox

After much painful configuration and fiddling, I've got to a point where I can at least access the default IIS site from my Mac (10.15.4).

I'm using NAT and have setup port forwarding as follows:

```
Host IP: 127.0.0.1; Host Port: 8000; Guest IP: 10.0.2.15; Guest Port: 80
Host IP: 127.0.0.1; Host Port: 8010; Guest IP: 10.0.2.15; Guest Port: 8000
```

`http://localhost:80` and `http://localhost:8000` both work when I test it locally from the Windows 10 VM, however only the one for port 80 works from my Mac, the one for 8000 gives me a 403 forbidden.

The site with port 8000 in IIS has a physical path pointing to my ASP.Net Framework project.

Even if I use IIS Express instead while debugging through Visual Studio on port `ABCDEF` (say), and I add a port forwarding rule for that port, I still get a 403 forbidden.

I've added additional Http-In rules to Windows Firewall to allow all traffic on the ports I'm forwarding to. I've noticed that if I don't do this, my http request from Mac just sits there hanging forever, but with these firewall rules in place, I seem to at least progress through to a 403.

I've even tried turning off Windows Firewall completely.

How do I access my site from Mac?

Comment: What are the site bindings? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: @LexLi The site’s bindings are located within the .vs directory of the project itself. I’ll share them once I’m back at my desk. Fyi, I tried installing Jexus via the msi installer but I ended up with an app file in the Start menu which Windows couldn’t figure out how to open.

Comment: What's the substatus and win32 status code of 403 error ? Please reviewe your IIS log and httperr log, you may find more details from them.

Comment: @JokiesDing There’s no substatus code, only says 403. Will check IIS logs to obtain further info.

Comment: Is there update with the 403 error.

Comment: @JokiesDing Not yet.